# Too long to load app

Tags: java, android, loading

How can i check why my app starting too long ?
This app starting about 5 second on real phone.

Last time i tried to make 2nd activity with splash screen for 5 seconds when my application starting but that was bad idea. 
It looked like this: `5 second to start -> splash -> next 5 sec -> app working`.
My idea caused two times more loading.
This application using `google maps`.

So how can i check why this loading is too long and how can i fix it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: how to determine cold start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385939/android-how-to-determine-cold-start)

Answer (score 0):

Try to checkout https://nimbledroid.com/ . Its a service, which would help you to find the cold start. Also you can look for your app's performance.

Try not to put to much (initialization) in MainApplication class unnecessarily.

There would be some cold start, if you have gcm or fcm in application.